# Content disappears behind the menu

Tags: html, css, gwt, layout

I have a gwt website and if I use the zoom function of my browser the content is displayed behind the menu. So no one can read the tables.

the used layout code looks like this:

```
<div id="globalContent" style="width: 100%;">
  <table class="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td align="left" colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
         <div id="headerContent"> </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px">
          <div id="navigationContent" class="" style="float: left">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <table class="navigationPanel" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"                         style="height: 100%;" aria-hidden="false"> /*menu goes here*/
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>              
            </div>
       </td>
       <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <div id="mainContent" style="float: left; width: 100%">
           <table class="bodyPanel" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 775px;"> /* Content goes here /* </table>
          </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Edit: Css

```
#globalContent { 
background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
.bodyPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-top: 70px;
  position: absolute;
}

.navigationPanel { /*border: 2px Black;*/
  width: 260px;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

When "navigationPanel" has position: fixed and mainContent has position: absolute.

The Content appears right of the menu but it ist 270px to width.

I have to support IE8 so I can't use CSS3 :-(

Comment: Provide css or a fiddle

Comment: I add some css and add some more code

Comment: you have unclosed div tag also i can;t render unless i see the populated html

Comment: I can't send you the whole html. It's generatet by gwt and if I copy the html there is the css and Java Script missing.

Comment: create a fidddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here is the full screen result. Some Images are missing. I hope that doesn't matter http://jsfiddle.net/MJUTF/embedded/result/

Comment: I don't see no problem in chrome..what browser are you having the problem

Comment: In this configuration the problem ist that the main content ist too big and you have to scroll to the right.

Comment: Oh sorry. 2 ways to solve this. Either make the iput field width less based on % or give the container overflow:auto so you get a scrollbar

Comment: Okay but I can't edit the input fields, it cost me a lot of time to place them so. And in this state I won't have a Scrollbar. I need the 100 % - 270px from the navigation.